# AppleScript: Use Dialog Return to Rename File

Tags: applescript, file-rename, automator

I'm attempting to create a Folder Action within Automator on Mac where when a new file is dropped into my specified folder, a dialog box opens asking which file I'm dropping in -- then, based on that selection, would automatically rename it to the dialog return and ideally a variable of today's date (while leaving the same extension).

Pretty new to AppleScripts but this is what I have so far which doesn't give me any errors but also doesn't do anything:

```
on run
    set theChoice to {"Option1", "Option2", "Option3", "Option4", "Other"}
    set selected to {choose from list theChoice}
    if selected is "Option1" then
        tell application "Finder"
            set currentFile to name of (selection as alias)
            set currentName to name of currentFile
            set name of currentFile to "Option1" & "." & name extension of currentFile
        end tell
    else if selected is "Option2" then
        tell application "Finder"
            set currentFile to name of (selection as alias)
            set currentName to name of currentFile
            set name of currentFile to "Option2" & "." & name extension of currentFile
        end tell
    else if selected is "Option3" then
        tell application "Finder"
            set currentFile to name of (selection as alias)
            set currentName to name of currentFile
            set name of currentFile to "Option3" & "." & name extension of currentFile
        end tell
    else if selected is "Option4" then
        tell application "Finder"
            set currentFile to name of (selection as alias)
            set currentName to name of currentFile
            set name of currentFile to "Option4" & "." & name extension of currentFile
        end tell
    else
        tell application "Finder"
            set currentFile to name of (selection as alias)
            set currentName to name of currentFile
            set name of currentFile to alias & "." & name extension of currentFile
        end tell
    end if
end run
```

After figuring this part out I was also hoping to add a today's date (e.g. "_20160510") variable to the end of each filename, so if that's possible to include also that'd be great.

Comment: You've only changed the name of the temporary variable `currentFile`. You probably need something like `set name of (selection as alias) to currentFile` as the final step.

Comment: @PaulR         Thanks -- I tried `tell application "Finder"
   set currentFile to name of (selection as alias)
   set currentName to name of currentFile
   set name of currentFile to "Option1" & "." & name extension of currentFile
   set name of (selection as alias) to currentFile
  end tell` but it didn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 2):

I've edited my quick answer. There may be other issues. I'll have to look at this a bit later. But this seems to work. You're going to have to get better at isolating smaller sections of code before putting too much together. Make sure you know what something returns first.

Look over the differences between the original code and this. You'll notice that

I added "without multiple selections"

You don't need to put `choose from list` in another list, so I've changed that, and gotten rid of "item 1 of item 1 of" because now selected is a simple list

I took out extra "name of"

I put in if/then to cover for cancel (which returns false)

```
on run
set theChoice to {"Option1", "Option2", "Option3", "Option4", "Other"}
set selected to (choose from list theChoice without multiple selections allowed)

if selected is not false then
    if item 1 of selected is "Option1" then
        tell application "Finder"
            set currentFile to (selection as alias)
            set currentName to name of currentFile
            set name of currentFile to "Option1" & "." & name extension of currentFile
        end tell
    else if item 1 of selected is "Option2" then
        tell application "Finder"
            set currentFile to (selection as alias)
            set currentName to name of currentFile
            set name of currentFile to "Option2" & "." & name extension of currentFile
        end tell
    else if item 1 of selected is "Option3" then
        tell application "Finder"
            set currentFile to (selection as alias)
            set currentName to name of currentFile
            set name of currentFile to "Option3" & "." & name extension of currentFile
        end tell
    else if item 1 of selected is "Option4" then
        tell application "Finder"
            set currentFile to (selection as alias)
            set currentName to name of currentFile
            set name of currentFile to "Option4" & "." & name extension of currentFile
        end tell
    else
        tell application "Finder"
            set currentFile to (selection as alias)
            set currentName to name of currentFile
            --set name of currentFile to alias & "." & name extension of currentFile
            --what is it you want to do here??
        end tell
    end if
end if
```

end run

**[EDIT]**

For suggestions in adding leading zeroes to date numbers, see http://www.foodoo.sunreal.com.au/info/date_info.html
it's old, but still appropriate.
Also, consider (if possible) using the  `do shell script` command, like:

```
do shell script "date +\"%m-%d-%y-%H-%M-%S\""
```

which will return something like

> "05-12-16-11-46"

( See http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-formatting-dates-for-display/ )

As for using this stuff in Automator, it may help to see what you're doing in Automator.

Comment: Thanks! Still need to work out some bugs it seems but you definitely made it closer. First issue is that sometimes it doesn't work? But sometimes it does. So I'll have to dig into that a bit more to see if there's a pattern. But secondly, when it does work -- it seems like it's suck in a loop? I'll select 'Option1' and (when it works) it'll change the file name perfectly to Option1, but then the dialog box pops open again? And it seems like I can continually change the name between all the options until I select one twice in a row.

Comment: I've made edits on the answer. And edited again b/c I left one of those "name of"s in there at end in the `else` section.

Comment: @Ryan Not sure what you're trying to do with the `else` part, actually. Could you explain why that is there? It doesn't work but we need to know what your intention is.

Comment: Also keep in mind that if there is already a file with that name it will fail. This works (aside from the else part) as rudimentary code but there's virtually no error correction.

Comment: Thanks -- there are still mild errors but I think the pattern is nailed down now. The renaming works, though I think the reason for the loop is because when we change the file name, the Folder Action from Automator gets reactivated. Is there any way to turn that off? Otherwise I suppose I can just hit 'cancel' after the first time.

Comment: And I guess the `else` was intended to say it's none of these options, don't do anything to the file name. But I suppose the 'cancel' option takes care of that as well? So we might be able to remove it.

Comment: Thanks again, whenever you can get around to updating it to the ideal version of this script, that'd be great. Fixing the 'other' part (which could essentially just be cancel and not rename it at all), hopefully stopping the loop with the folder action, and finally it seems like when I do it manually, it works but if it's automated by another folder action, the list options show up but it doesn't rename anything?

Comment: Make sure you read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and review the best way to ask for help. The site is not a 'do coding for me'-type-thing. Try to be specific and give examples of your own attempts.

Comment: Yup didn't mean it to come off like that sorry! You just asked for more info and said that there might be some issues and that you would come back to it later so was just making sure you understood the issues I was having when I used your code. I already updated it on my end to include the current date variable `set name of currentFile to ("FullVANExport_" & (year of (current date)) & (month of (current date)) * 1 & day of (current date) as string) & "." & name extension of currentFile` though I can't figure out how to get leading zeros. Beyond that trying to figure out the loop

Comment: Thanks again! And nothing really in Automator -- just put the AppleScript in there and used the folder action in Automator when a file hits the folder since I feel more comfortable with that than with AppleScript

Answer (score 0):

This is a shorter version of the script summarizing redundant code

```
set theChoice to {"Option1", "Option2", "Option3", "Option4", "Other"}
set selected to {choose from list theChoice}
if theChoice is false then return
set chosen to item 1 of theChoice

tell application "Finder" to set theSelection to selection
if theSelection is {} then return
set currentFile to item 1 of theSelection

set currentDate to do shell script "date +%Y%d%m"

if chosen is "Other" then
    tell application "Finder"
        -- do something with "Other"
    end tell
else
    tell application "Finder"
        set name of currentFile to chosen & "_" & currentDate & "." & name extension of currentFile
    end tell
end if
```

Comment: Thank you! This is much cleaner. I was testing this out though and when I put in in AppleScript at least the syntax is good but when I put it in Automator it says `Can’t set selected to {choose from list theChoice}. Access not allowed.` And when I put back my old script it says `Can’t set selected to choose from list theChoice without multiple selections allowed. Access not allowed.` All I'm doing in Automator is using it for the folder action -- the rest is just this code. Any ideas? Haven't seen this before.